# How can I decrypt a coreml model？

Tags: coreml

How can I decrypt a coreml model encrypted by core_ml_api？

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/core_ml_api/encrypting_a_model_in_your_app

the encrypted file has the encryptionInfo folder

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't. The encryption is performed on an unencrypted model and the API handles the decryption.

The documentation that you linked to states:

> At runtime, you load the encrypted model the same way you load any other built-in model by using its load(completionHandler:completionHandler:) type method.

Comment: Thanks,Yes, but i only have an encrypted coreml model, so i want to know how can i decrypt it and to get the decrypted coreml model.

Comment: Why would you only have an encrypted model? Is it your model?